# In what case would Neo4J's Rest API return a 404 Not Found?

Tags: neo4j

I'm writing a batch job to POST to /db/data/batch in Neo4J a la the documentation here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.4/rest-api-batch-ops.html.

I'm creating a Node via a POST operation, then creating a relationship via POST from a previously existing node, to the one created in the batch. Neo4J returns a 404 - Not Found on the relationship URL for the ***previously existing*** Node.

Here's the request:

```
[ {
    "method" : "POST",
    "to"     : "/node",
    "id"     : 0,
    "body"   : {
      "entityType"  : "TimeOff",
      "start"       : "2014-08-13",
      "end"         : "2014-08-13",
      "status"      : "Approve",
      "reqId"       : 13579
    }
  }, {
    "method" : "POST",
    "to"     : "/node/1234/relationships",
    "id"     : 1,
    "body"   : {
      "to"   : "{0}",
      "type" : "REQUEST"
    }
  }
]
```

If I repeat this via SSH and cURL, it works without issue. Same database server, and same application server. The 404 seems to result from "/node/1234/relationships", even though cURL GETs to "/node/1234" and "/node/1234/relationships/all" work fine, as well as a POST via cURL.

I feel like there is something wrong with the server that is causing a 404, maybe due to a time-out or similar. Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you just use Cypher here?

Comment: What library do you use for the batch-api calls? Perhaps it misses some accept or content-type header for application/json somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better is to use the new transactional endpoint, and do Cypher statements, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE id(n) = 1234
WITH n
CREATE (node:TimeOff{reqId:1234}) -[:REQUEST]->(n)
```

Comment: I wound up using cypher for some parts, but this is a relatively old system, and would require a lot of cypher in a lot of places (this is just one example). Worthy, but difficult and time consuming. Besides, the Batch RestAPI exists for this purpose, yet seems to be poorly implemented and documented.

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer, but I have to say, from my last couple of weeks of use Neo, it's not worth using in a production environment.

Comment: What is the problem? The REST API, Cypher or the Batch endpoint?

Comment: Apologies for the very delayed reply. The problem is with the Batch endpoint, where referencing nodes created in a previous batch entry, for use in creating a relationship, or adding to an index. The created node via batch, does not seem to be available in the context, as is described in the documentation. It could be worked around by either having a planned id, or doing multiple batches, but then maybe the documentation should be updated to indicate that created nodes are not really available in the same batch.